# ExpandoMetaClass getMetaMethods() doesn't return added methods

Tags: groovy

While debugging Grails app I've found Groovy's behaviour which seems to be a bit strange. Let's say I would like to add some method to `String` class:

```
String.metaClass.myMethod = {
    println 'Hello'
}
```

Then I try to get list of meta methods with `getMetaMethods()` but it doesn't contain this method. I know that there's `getExpandoMethods()` which works correctly but shouldn't meta method added to class be also contained in `metaMethods` list? Especially when `getMetaMethod()` works as expected. Code below:

```
def emptyArray = new Object[0];
assert String.metaClass.getMetaMethods().collect { it.name }.contains('myMethod') == false
assert String.metaClass.getMetaMethod('myMethod', emptyArray) != null

// and again with instance   
def text2 = 'Just for testing...'
assert text2.metaClass.getMetaMethods().collect { it.name }.contains('myMethod') == false
assert text2.metaClass.getMetaMethod('myMethod', emptyArray) != null
```

And this is even more strange if I try to get expando methods before:

```
def text = 'Again just for testing...'
text.metaClass.getExpandoMethods() // strange, but let's try...
assert text.metaClass.getMetaMethods().collect { it.name }.contains('myMethod') == true
assert text.metaClass.getMetaMethod('myMethod', emptyArray) != null
```

Tested with Groovy 2.3.6 and 2.2.2.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a bug to me -- esp. due to that last case where the side-effect of calling `getExpandoMethods` was that it was also added to the meta methods list. When looking at the groovy source, I see that `getMetaMethod('myMethod')` results in a call to `getMethodWithoutCaching`, which is interesting. Perhaps this is a caching issue?

Comment: I haven't run your code and not sure why the method wouldn't be in the metaMethods property but it would almost certainly be in the methods property... `String.metaClass.methods.find {it.name == 'myMethod'}`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks, I know that it's possible to retrieve this method with getMethods() or getExpandoMetaMethods(). Unfortunately I've found this behaviour while debugging my Grails app while trying to upgrade Grails. I've submitted pull request and hope it will be accepted & merged - https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/pull/44